# Keyswitch one or two words?

Tags: word-choice

I work with electronic circuits terminology a lot and I sometimes see key switch (two words) and keyswitch (one word).  I was wondering which one is right ?

The word is to designate a switch activated by a physical key that has to be inserted.

e.g. Elevator override *keyswitch/key switch* located at the main floor.

Comment: It may depend on the context, or could be just random people spelling it different ways.

Comment: Logically, it *should* be one word. However, until the "word" is recognized and documented (in some authentic document somewhere), it may be necessary to use the phrase, maybe with a hyphen for the time being: *key-switch* HTH.

Comment: @Kris how so *should* above? Also the querent reports that they can attest for its use themselves.

Comment: This ["Idiots Guide to Components of Electrical Circuits"](http://www.tutorvista.com/content/science/science-ii/electricity/electric-circuits-components.php) says *The **switch** or **key** helps to make or break the circuit, i.e. switches on or switches off the current.* I'm not an electronics engineer, but it seems to me for the sense under consideration most instances where *both* words are used (fused into a single word, hyphenated, or two separate words) are actually from Far Eastern scientists not writing in their native language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers there's plenty of cases where other uses of *keyswitch* or *key switch* could be confusable with the sort you'd have for an elevator override, but I don't think that link shows one of them.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: Try googling a few variants like **elevator key lock, elevator keyswitch, secure area keylock, secure area key switch**. I find a lot more *Chinese* sites using ***switch***, particularly when conjoined with ***key*** as a single-word form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a compound, and often compounds can exist in different people's use, between open (*key switch*), closed (*keyswitch*) and hyphenated (*key-switch*).

Generally compounds start out open or hyphenated (note also, in many people's use it might be open when used as a noun and hyphenated when used as a modifier, so someone who said "protected by a key switch" might say "key-switch protection") and if they're used a lot then more and more people will start using them closed and they'll "become a word".

But they can also co-exist in two forms for a long time, or even three (*egg-beater*, *egg beater* and *eggbeater* have been each going for some time).

So, if more than a handful of people are using a particular form, then it's reasonable to consider it **a** correct form, but not necessarily **the** correct form.

Your own question points out that both *key switch* and *keyswitch* are in use, and suggests that they're both in enough use that both could be considered correct.

We can try some surveying, though I hasten to add that there are a lot of caveats with this source:

[image]

This shows *key-switch* not being used a lot, and we can imagine that it actually overestimates the number due to what I mentioned above about people hyphenating some open compounds when they are modifiers.

It shows *key switch* being much more commonly used than *keyswitch*.

This is also quite likely overestimating *keyswitch* here because *keyswitch* is also used for a type of switch that is used to make keyboards. The fact that this sort of keyboard design is less common now and *keyswitch* has declined toward the end of the 1990s backs this theory up.

It may though also overestimate *key switch* too, because the combination could occur in wider phrases with different meanings. So we aren't conclusive yet.

So we look [through results for both term and see which are more often in use](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=&as_oq=%22keyswitch%22+OR+%22key+switch%22&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=&gws_rd=ssl). Again while we find *keyswitch* and *key switch* both in use for this sort of term, we find the latter considerably more often than the former (discounting other uses of either). Not a massive survey of the language, but enough to be reasonably confident *key switch* is definitely getting considerable use here.

And as such we can conclude that *key switch* is much more often used than *keyswitch* in this context.

It's enough to give us confidence that *key switch* is certainly correct. Whether we can conclude that *keyswitch* is incorrect or also correct but less popular requires both more dependable data than this and a consensus on when an English word can be considered "correct" that we are never going to see.

But we can conclude that unless you really, really just like *keyswitch* better, it might be a good idea to use *key switch* but not complain about anyone who uses *keyswitch* either.

Comment: There is a problem with the statistic for the expression "key switch", because that combination can easily occur in sentences that have nothing to do with the OP's hardware. For instance: "The **key switch** that enabled Team A's win on Saturday was replacing the injury-prone Player X with Player Y as a striker". Clearly, many false positives could be generated by such uses of the term.

Comment: @ErikKowal thanks. I thought I'd covered the issues with the results for all three terms, but I did indeed skip those for that one.